# Flutter retrieving label input from buttons to textfield

Tags: flutter, user-input

Here is my code. Now I want when "ElevatedButton" is pressed to get that number what is labeled on button to textfield. Like you can see I have two textfields, also I need to make them selectable. When you press on textfield then you focused them and you can input the number.

The application is calculator of points for the card game shown here.

````
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GameScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const GameScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ignore: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
      const Spacer(),
      // ignore: avoid_unnecessary_containers
      SizedBox(
          height: 100,
          child: Row(children: const [
            Expanded(
                child: Text(
              "MI",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
            )),
            Expanded(
                child: Text(
              "VI",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
            )),
          ])),
      const Spacer(),
      Row(
        children: [TextField(), TextField()],
      ),
      const Spacer(),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              // ignore: deprecated_member_use
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 20, bottom: 20, right: 20, left: 20)),
                  child: const Text('CONTACTS',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 30,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 20, bottom: 20, right: 50, left: 50)),
                  child: const Text('POINTS',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 30,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
      const Spacer(),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 20, bottom: 20, right: 50, left: 50)),
                  child:
                      const Text('7', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 20, bottom: 20, right: 50, left: 50)),
                  child:
                      const Text('8', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 20, bottom: 20, right: 50, left: 50)),
                  child:
                      const Text('9', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
      const Spacer(),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 20, bottom: 20, right: 50, left: 50)),
                  child:
                      const Text('4', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 20, bottom: 20, right: 50, left: 50)),
                  child:
                      const Text('5', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 20, bottom: 20, right: 50, left: 50)),
                  child:
                      const Text('6', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
      const Spacer(),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 20, bottom: 20, right: 50, left: 50)),
                  child:
                      const Text('1', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 20, bottom: 20, right: 50, left: 50)),
                  child:
                      const Text('2', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 20, bottom: 20, right: 50, left: 50)),
                  child:
                      const Text('3', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
      const Spacer(),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 20, bottom: 20, right: 40, left: 40)),
                  child: const Text('Del 1',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 20, bottom: 20, right: 50, left: 50)),
                  child:
                      const Text('0', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 20, bottom: 20, right: 40, left: 40)),
                  child: const Text('Clear',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
      const Spacer(),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 20, bottom: 20, right: 70, left: 70)),
                  child: const Text('SAVE GAME',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 40,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
      const Spacer(),
    ])));
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example to get `Button` text to `TextField` !Modify this according to your requirement.

declare `TextEditingController` s:

```
TextEditingController cont1 = TextEditingController(),
      cont2 = TextEditingController();
```

And build method:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      Row(
        children: [
        Expanded(
          child: TextField(
            controller: cont1,
            //other params
          ),
        ),
          const Spacer(flex: 1),
        Expanded(
          child: TextField(
            controller: cont2,
            //other params
          ),
        ),
      ]),
      ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState((){ //or other state management
              cont1.text = "8";
            });
          },
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 20, bottom: 20, right: 50, left: 50)),
          child: const Text('8', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
    ]);
  }
```